# representive Vertex cycle cover

Tags: algorithm, graph, vertex-cover

This problem may be related to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23121799/4619633).

This problem also [asked here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/229108/47056) but with a different taste.

Consider an (undirected) square graph with a periodic boundary condition. Then find a complete cycle graph with length equal to 4. now I want to assign a unique representative to each cycle from its elements. Therefore in a square graph with n_v vertex i will find n_f=n_v 4-cycles and n_v representative for the cycles. For the square graph, everything is simple. just assign the bottom left vertex of each plaque(4-cycles).

[image]

(i just show first 4-cycle)

Now, I want to generalize it for other structures. consider (undirected) kagome  graph with proper boundary condition,

[image]

(here I just show 3 distinct cycles)

In this case for assigning a vertex to cycles cover, you need three different length cycles. which show by similar color with the assigned vertex. However, now I want to generalize this to other complicated graphs.  I want to know is this problem has a name and about its possibility or algorithm. For example, we cannot do it in a triangular graph:

[image]

Comment: By cycle, do you mean face in the planar graph as you have embedded it?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat, yes. Actually I define cycle to identifies faces.

Comment: I know a fair amount about planar graphs, but with the periodic boundary condition, we're moving into a part of the subject I know less about. It seems to me that you're dealing in graphs on a torus. A necessary condition is V = F (number of vertices equals faces), which implies that the average degree of both must be 4 by Euler's formula (which rules out the triangles). Interestingly both of your positive examples are self-dual, but I don't see why that should be a necessary or sufficient condition.

Comment: Oh, no the second isn't self dual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem solved [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/229145/47056).

- I)Let show all faces and vertices by \alpha_i, where i contain
  vertices and faces.
- II) make a graph which relates \alpha_i (from i
  in face group) to \alpha_j (to j in vertex group), if j(vortex)
  belong to i(face).
- III) find [the independent edge set](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IndependentEdgeSet.html) of this
  graph gives for any vortex a face.

Please see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/229145/47056) for additional information.